# Is it possible to implement SIP (session initiation protocol) server on FPGA if yes than how

Tags: sip, fpga, voip, cortex-m, sip-server

i have FPGA that also has a cortex m3 processor so can i implement a sip server on this chip ,what  should be the approach for doing this

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at PJSIP implementation very low footprint:
http://www.pjsip.org/about.htm#compact